# Passing array of pointers to template class method

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers

Briefly, I have a template class Tree which has a `createTree(Data* arrayData[])` method. This method receives an array of pointers to data of type Data :

```
template<class Data>
void Tree<Data>::createTree(Data* arrayData[]) {
    m_indexCreation = 0;
    cout << sizeof(arrayData) / sizeof(int) << endl;
    m_root = createChildTree(arrayData);
}
```

In my `main()` function, I create an array of pointers to string objects and fill it. I then try to pass it to the `createTree()` method, but inside the method the array becomes of size 1. In other words, the count inside the method prints "1".
Here's my `main()` :

```
int main() {
    string* tab[20];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ ) {
        if ( i % 3 != 0 ) {
            tab[i] = new string("James Johnson");
        } else {
            tab[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    Tree<string> tree;
    tree.createTree(tab);

    tree.display(tree.getRoot());
}
```

I can print without problem the values of the whole array in the `main()`, but in `createTree()`, the array somehow reduces to a size of 1, with single value of NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof(tabDonnees) / sizeof(int)` probably produces 1. You're dividing the size of a pointer by the size of an int. Also, the method creerArbre (createTree) cannot determine the size of `tab`, it is only passed in by address, and it does not store its size, nor does the compiler pass its size.

Comment: @Alexis Leclerc, hi Alexis, welcome to SO. Please take into account that most of users of SO are worldwide developer. It's is a bad idea to post code that is either in french, spanish, indian, or deutsch, or arabic or anything. I translated it.

Comment: @StephaneRolland - does it matter? His Question itself was in English. Only classnames, function names were in a different language. And didn't matter.

Comment: @user93353 well it does'nt matter for me I am French, and his code was in French ;-) But I remember when I saw Hindi, Indonesian, variable names and functions... It really didn't help me understand what was going on in the code... We are in a international site of inter-aid. If you ask Meta I think I read one Q/A that stated the English was the language of this site. That's what I remember. Maybe there were answers stating the contrary was acceptable inside the code, but I don't remember them. ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I'll translate my code next time ;)
and thanks for translating !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the C FAQ

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html

> A: The compiler pretends that the array parameter was declared as a pointer (that is, in the example, as char *a; see question 6.4), and sizeof reports the size of the pointer. See also questions 1.24 and 7.28.

The workaround. Pass the size as a parameter.

```
void Tree<Data>::createTree(Data* arrayData[], int sz)
{
    ...
}

Tree<string> tree;
tree.createTree(tab, sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

When `tab` is sent into the function it will undergo array-to-pointer conversion:

From the C++ Standard, 4.2 [Standard Conversions]

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the ﬁrst element of the array.

Thus, your initial signature will look similar to this:

```
Tree<Data>::createTree(Data** arrayData);
```

As you can see `arrayData` because a double-pointer. When you use `sizeof`, it will return the number of bytes for the *pointer* but not for the actual array. To fix this, you should pass the array through a reference:

```
template <class Data, unsigned N>
createTree(Data* (&arrayData)[N]); // you can print out N for the size
//                                    but sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x) will still work
```

Or you can use `std::vector` as it is much easier to obtain the size:

```
#include <vector>

void Tree<Data>::createTree(std::vector<Data*> arrayData)
{
    std::cout << arrayData.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tab;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) // shortened for this example
    {
        tab[i] = new std::string("James Johnson");
    }

    ...
}
```

This in my opinion is a cleaner alternative. I hope this helped.